# ASP.NET MVC 3 trying to setup https via IIS7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, entity-framework-4.1

**ASP.NET + MVC 3 + IIS7.0 + HTTPS requests**

In short how do I setup HTTPS requests in IIS7.0 (NB: I am not using IIS express). Ideally only for the events in my AccountController is all I need but I can come back to that. I have read up on a few posts and I getting to understand them however I guess I just need direction as I am not sure what is going on. What I have done is as follows:

Web.Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MyMVCAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20" protection="All" requireSSL="true"/>
</authentication>
```

In IIS7.0:

1. Created a new website by adding the path to my code and used the DefaultAppPool
2. I edited the permissions and added IIS_IUSRS user with "read & execute"
3. Changed the DefaultAppPool to use the latest .NET framework
4. Created a new Self Signed Certificate and added a https binding
5. My "Default Web Site" which was pointing to port 80 I stopped and applied the default ports of 80 and 443 to my new site.

Ran my application thru VS "MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express" with debug=true and removed an offending line of targetFramework="4.0" which it did not like. However, clicking on my [Log On] link my CSS styles have been removed!?!? Do I need to specify the port number via VS some how? Via VWD it chooses a random port number and when you click on the hyperlink it removes the port number?
[image: ASP.NET MVC 3 IIS7 Application ScreenShots]

Answer (score 2):

Since you have created a self signed certificate, IE doesn't recognize it coming from a valid certification authority and it warns you about when you navigate to the website. You could ignore the warning by continuing to the web page. The same ting happens with your CSS and javascrpt links. So here's what you could do: Copy-Paste the link to your CSS and JS files into the browser address bar (with HTTPS) and ignore the warning. Then refresh the actual page (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) and the styles should reappear.

Comment: I tried https://localhost/Content/Cite.css but I get a Server Error in '/' Application "The resource cannot be found"

Comment: I believe this sight formatted it that way and I left for the day before I realised, so yes I did put the https in front. Any other suggestions?